# Microsoft Access VBA: Combine text values by using an expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi I have built a login form for both trainers and members, they can both login into one form. However I would like to make sure when either the trainer or the member logs in, the message box pops up and should say. "Welcome =[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]". So basically after welcome the members or the trainers fullname is displayed.

Can someone please help me out, would really appreciate it, Thanks. My code is shown below.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command9_Click()

    Dim isTrainer As Boolean, isMember As Boolean

    isTrainer = DCount("TrainerFirstName", "tbl4_Trainers", _
                 "TrainerEmail = [txtEmail] And TrainerPassword = [txtPassword] ") > 0
    isMember = DCount("MemberFirstName", "tbl1_Members", _
                 "MemberEmail = [txtEmail] And MemberPassword = [txtPassword] ") > 0

    If isTrainer Or isMember Then
        MsgBox ("Welcome & = [TrainerFirstName] & " " & [TrainerLastName] or = [MemberFirstName] & " " & [MemberLastName] ")
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"
        If isTrainer Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm3_Main Menu"
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm2_Member Class Registration"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox ("Login Failed")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate variables. If fields are text type, parameters need apostrophe delimiters.

```
isTrainer = DCount("TrainerFirstName", "tbl4_Trainers", _
             "TrainerEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail & "' And TrainerPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword & "'") > 0
isMember = DCount("MemberFirstName", "tbl1_Members", _
             "MemberEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail & "' And MemberPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword & "'") > 0
```

Need conditional to construct the welcome MsgBox text. Don't use the MsgBox function, just MsgBox OkOnly.

`MsgBox "Welcome " & IIf(isTrainer, [TrainerFirstName] & " " & [TrainerLastName], [MemberFirstName] & " " & [MemberLastName])`

`MsgBox "Login Failed"`

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. Better form names would be:
frm1_MemberTrainerLogin
frm2_MemberClassRegistration
frm3_MainMenu

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you miss the full name. Use *DLookup* for that:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()

    Dim Trainer As Variant
    Dim Member As Variant

    Trainer = DLookup("[TrainerFirstName] & ' ' & [TrainerLastName]", "tbl4_Trainers", _
                 "TrainerEmail = '" & [txtEmail] & "' And TrainerPassword = '" &[txtPassword] & "'")
    Member = DLookup("[MemberFirstName] & ' ' & [MemberLastName]", "tbl1_Members", _
                 "MemberEmail = '" & [txtEmail] & "' And MemberPassword = '" &[txtPassword] & "'")

    ' To debug:
    MsgBox "Trainer: '" & Trainer & "'" & vbCrLf & "Member: '" & Member & "'"
    ' Note the revised logic: + -> &
    If Not IsNull(Trainer & Member) Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & Nz(Trainer, Member)
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"

        If Not IsNull(Trainer) Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm3_Main Menu"
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm2_Member Class Registration"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Login Failed"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I kepp recieving the message "Login Failed". Can you plase help me solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Yes. My logic was wrong - login would fail if either Trainer or Member was not found. Se comments in edited answer, please.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, you really helped me out a lot, and once again thanks for your help, hope you all the best in the future.